# Determining the length of an image and a portion of it

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, string-length

I am trying to get the length of an image as well as the length of a portion of it, but both  give the same result. Where did I go wrong?

**Part of area of image:**

```
private BufferedImage add_text(BufferedImage image, String text) {
    BufferedImage imageLocation=image.getSubimage(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2, 
            image.getWidth()-image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()-image.getHeight()/2);

    byte img[] = get_byte_data(imageLocation);
    System.out.println("Image length: "+img.length);
```

**Whole image:**

```
private BufferedImage add_text(BufferedImage image, String text) {

    byte img[] = get_byte_data(image);
    System.out.println("Image length: "+img.length);
```

**The output of both is**

> Image length: 984900

Comment: What is the length of an image?

Comment: Here you are getting length of the byte array. Not the actual image.You should use  imageLocation.getWidth() and imageLocation.getHeight().

Comment: What the definition of `get_byte_data`?

Comment: if you want to get size of a portion of image in bytes in a particular format (lets say JPEG) u need to create a new bitmap copy the contents you want( the portion of the image ) and then store that as byte stream in a MemeoryStream object and then get length. If this is indeed your question

Comment: Sorry, my poor English. It should be getting length of the image byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are getting length of the byte array. Not the actual image.
You should use  `imageLocation.getWidth()` and `imageLocation.getHeight()`.

If you have checked the java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html
it says that getSubimage method shares the same data array as the original image.
That is why you are getting same length for the data array length.

Comment: Thank you Srinath. But i have a question, because i want to put a message in this part of area, so i need to exactly location of this area. 
`private byte[] get_byte_data(BufferedImage image) {
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();`
In this image here is the original image?? or the part of image??

Comment: @JarekHuang , if you just need to print some text on the original image it's much more easier. Check the answer for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658554/using-graphics2d-to-overlay-text-on-a-bufferedimage-and-return-a-bufferedimage

Comment: Actually, i am trying to put the invisible message into the image, but i want to put it to difference part of image.
This is a link i am asking [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127860/put-invisible-message-in-four-part-of-image-by-using-raster

Comment: Because i need to know the 
x - the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
y - the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
w - the width of the specified rectangular region
h - the height of the specified rectangular region

if i just use `imageLocation.getWidth() and imageLocation.getHeight()` , it will not have exactly rectangular region i wanted.

Comment: @JarekHuang I think you have mixed up Steganography concepts and Java image manipulation. I'll answer your other question on Steganography since it doesn't relate directly to this question.