# Exception in thread "Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d, imageicon

The only thing difference is there is two different crop location.
The question is why i get this error??

**Method call**

```
CropRealOriginalImage1 orderName = new CropRealOriginalImage1();
        FourAreaCropAgain1 orderNameFirst=new FourAreaCropAgain1();
        orderNameFirst.orderNameFirst();
        Decode decode= new Decode();
        decode.inputImage("C:/TEMP/Image/Embed Image/Four Area/OrderFirst.png");
        if(decode.s.equals("")){
            System.out.println("OderFirst=null");
        }else{
            //put b into txt file
            System.out.println("decode.s" +decode.s);
        }
```

**Work:**

```
  public void orderNameFirst(){
       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/TEMP/Image/Embed Image/Really Original.png");
    image = icon.getImage();
    image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(),
        new CropImageFilter(icon.getIconWidth()-290, 0, 10, 33)));
            //new CropImageFilter(icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2, icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2)));

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
            icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

    Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(icon.getIconWidth()-290, 0, 10, 33);

 }
```

**Not Work**

```
   public void orderNameFirst(){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/TEMP/Image/Embed Image/Really Original.png");
    image = icon.getImage();
    image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(),
        new CropImageFilter(3*icon.getIconWidth()/8, 0, icon.getIconWidth()/8, icon.getIconHeight()/2)));
            //new CropImageFilter(icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2, icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2)));

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
            icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

    Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(3*icon.getIconWidth()/8, 0, icon.getIconWidth()/8, icon.getIconHeight()/2);
   }
```

**Error:**  Decode integerLength: 2147483647
Exception in thread "Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Requested array size exceeds VM limit -- Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: (In addition to actually asking a question, you should copy the exception stack trace into your question and identify the line in your code that corresponds to the exception.)

Comment: @JarekHuang: In addition to the stack trace, post image and icon dimensions. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: This might not be the answer you want, but this is what you asked for.

> The question is why i get this error??

You get the error:

```
 Exception in thread "Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

...because you are trying to create an array that is larger than the maximum contiguous block of memory in your Java VMs heap. This can happen either because you are trying to create a humongously large image, or it could be that your VM is just generally running low on resources at the time you try to allocate the array.

This most likely happens inside one of the `BufferedImage` constructors.

But it's hard to say, as you haven't posted the full stack trace, nor the relevant information about the images' sizes or other values actually passed around in your program at runtime.

The fix depends on the reason for running out of memory.

As an example, I can see from your code that you never invoke `dispose` on the `Graphics/Graphics2D` instances you are creating. This will likely cause a resource leak over time (just an example, there might be others).

If you just run out of memory immediately, because the image is huge, you need to increase the maximum heap size. This is typically done, by passing a `-Xmx<value>` argument to the `java` command line (where `<value>` is the new max size, like `256m`, `1G` or similar).