# How to enlarge the maximum length of bytes array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

When I ran the code below:

```java
        List<Data> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        long totalSize = bis.available();

        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("data file size:" + totalSize + " bytes");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
        bis.read(bytes);
```

an error occured, which was:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
load data_info end
time cost:367ms
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data file size:2147483647 bytes
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at com.IO.loadDat(IO.java:83)
    at com.GetData.main(GetData.java:26)
```

I haven't solved the problem yet, I wonder how to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception in thread "Thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633505/exception-in-thread-thread-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-requested-array-size-ex) This happens because the file you are trying to load is using up more memory than your JVM (or system) has available. Check the size of the file, and check the maximum memary limit of your application/PC. Note that depending on the OS, architecture (32bit etc), or VM type, that the limit could easily be as low as 2GB

Comment: When starting the JVM, add `-Xmx8G` as a java option. But regarding `byte[] bytes = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE];` do you really need a 2Gb array?

Comment: Much appreciated. I think the 2Gb array is required, because the file contains 2147483647 bytes data. I ran my code on the windows server, which contains at least 40g memory. Therefore, I wonder how to allocate memory to enlarge the length of the array in Java